# Pass Elastic Beanstalk configuration without = sign

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

So I am trying to turn on the G1 garbage collector using the terraform config template: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template#setting

All I need to do is pass in -XX:+UseG1GC to the JVM options, but I am getting an = sign injected between the name and value (and value is required).

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Please post the Terraform code you are using.

Comment: jvm_options = [{
      namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions"
      name      = "XX:"
      value     = "+UseG1GC"
    }]

Comment: That's the only Terraform code you have? And please add it to the question not in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Elastic Beanstalk documentation [1], it seems that if you need to pass a specific JVM option you need to use that as the name, i.e.:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template" "yourappname" {
  name                = "<yourconfigtemplatename>"
  application         = "<yourbeanstalkapplicationname>"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions"
    name      = "JVM Options"
    value     = "-XX:+UseG1GC"
  }
}
```

As I am not a Beanstalk expert it might require a coupe of iterations to get it right.

EDIT: As per Mark B's comment, I was missing a hyphen in the value, so I have added that as well.

---

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-java

Comment: I think it would actually be `"-XX:+UseG1GC"`. You left out the `-`.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for spotting that. :)